# Sass is breaking on @extend ".bg-faded"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, railsapps

I used Rails Composer to create a skeleton application for the rails-devise-roles project described here:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise-roles

I'm getting a 500 error generated by the following:

```
Sass::SyntaxError - ".authform form" failed to @extend ".bg-faded".
The selector ".bg-faded" was not found.
Use "@extend .bg-faded !optional" if the extend should be able to fail.
```

Adding the "!optional" flag allows it to render, but none of the navigation links are then displayed.

Contents of my Gemfile are displayed below:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
ruby '2.2.5'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
gem 'devise'
gem 'high_voltage'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'unicorn'
gem 'unicorn-rails'
group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8):

Changing `@extend .bg-faded` to `@extend .bg-light` will fix your error

Comment: This is a known issue with the rails composer gem: https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer/issues/273

Answer (score 2):

Its most likely because you haven't imported the framework CSS. Add these to your application.scss file

```
// import the CSS framework
@import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the bootstrap line in your gemfile to `gem 'bootstrap', '= 4.0.0.alpha6'`